# Generating a response surface from a fractionated design

Tags: experiment-design, fractional-factorial

Is it possible and valid to generate a response surface through augmentation of a fractionated factorial design, where all main effects and two factor interactions have no bias from any other main effects or two factor interactions (a resolution V design)?

Comment: This is a little short for a question? Why do you think there would be a problem?

Comment: Could you explain how this differs from [your previous question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200077)?

Comment: It would help others looking at this site to say a bit about what a "resolution V design" is, to describe the type of underlying subject-matter question you are trying to solve, and the problems that you fear will arise in your proposed approach.

Comment: There was a problem with the site and I had a response saying the question had been deleted (?). My issue is around what information could be lost, is there a higher likelihood of lack of fit, model fitting not always leading to good prediction. I am not a statistician, but I know some basics.

Comment: I've also opted to delete the previous question

Comment: Does "augment" here mean conduct a *subsequent* experiment with different design points? Did your fractional factorial expt also include centre points?

Comment: The augmentation of the design here means to generate two axial points for every factor (where that factor is at +1 and -1, and all other levels are the centre values, 0) so as to give variance at a said point that is only dependent on that point's distance from the centre point. The intention is to run multiple centre points, yes.

Comment: I'm trying to distinguish (1) the case where you're *planning* a sequential experiment with (potential) augmentation from (2) the case where you've *already* performed a fractional factorial experiment & *now* want to augment it: if it's the latter did the fractional factorial experiment include centre points?

Comment: It's the former

Comment: Well, yes; that's quite standard: see e.g. http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pri/section3/pri3364.htm